# Password authentication with mupdf is not working

Tags: android, pdf, mupdf

For me Mupdfcore.authenticatePassword("password") is not working.. Pdf files without password protection renders correctly but ones with password results into an error.

```
error : AES padding out of range : 154
```

Can anyone please help me..?

Answer (score 1):

`authenticatePassword(String password)` is not implemented in MuPDFCore.
Use `MuPDFCore.authenticatePasswordInternal(password)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the file in question, it's very hard to make a judgement on this - there are simply too many possible combinations of security revision/versions within Acrobat.

Why not come to the #ghostscript irc channel and speak to the devs? See the link on http://mupdf.com if you don't have an irc client.

We'll probably ask you to make the file available to us via our bug tracker at http://bugs.ghostscript.com/ - we can mark it 'private' so it's not world readable if you want to keep it confidential.